# Error in pom file in Maven project after importing into Eclipse

Tags: android, maven-plugin, m2eclipse, android-maven-plugin

I am actually new to the Maven framework. I already have a Maven project. I installed the Maven plugin etc into my EclipseIDE from http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e. Then I imported my project and enabled dependencies, but the project is showing too many errors. The pom.xml itself is showing errors. The errors are

```
Project Build Error:unknown packaging:apk
Project Build Error:unresolvable build extension:plugin"
```

etc.

My error area is:

```
project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.nbc.cnbc.android</groupId>
<artifactId>android.domain.tests</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>apk</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.nbc.cnbc.android</groupId>
    <artifactId>android.domain.parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <relativePath>../android.domain.parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<name>android.domain.tests</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
```

Could it be because the url specified in the last line could be different?
Any ideas why this could be happening?
Any reply is highly appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance!!

Answer (score 10):

You have installed the "normal" Maven plugin that works for Java projects (and .jar files).
For Android you need the [Maven Android Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/EclipseIntegration)

Personally, I think that Android Maven is too much of a hassle for the few dependencies that I use in my projects, but this is how I set it up when I tried it out:

- Set the ANDROID_HOME variable to your SDK root location and add the SDK's `tools` and `platform-tools` folders to your path (more info see [this link](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/GettingStarted))
- Start Eclipse and enable "Dependency management" on your Android project.
- Make sure you include [Maven Central](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/) to you repositories and add the following to your pom (more info see [this link](http://www.simpligility.com/2010/06/android-artifacts-hit-maven-central/) or [this link](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/QuickStartForEclipseProject)).

> ```
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
>   <artifactId>android</artifactId>
>   <version>2.3.3</version>
>   <scope>provided</scope>
> </dependency>
>
> <build>
>    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
>    <plugins>
>        <plugin>
>            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
>            <configuration>
>                <source>1.6</source>
>                <target>1.6</target>
>            </configuration>
>        </plugin>
>        <plugin>
>            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
>            <artifactId>maven-android-plugin</artifactId>
>            <configuration>
>                <sdk>
>                   <path>${env.ANDROID_HOME}</path>
>                    <platform>10</platform>
>                </sdk>
>                <deleteConflictingFiles>true</deleteConflictingFiles>
>            </configuration>
>            <extensions>true</extensions>
>        </plugin>
>    </plugins>
> </build>
> ```

Off course you can adjust the android version to your liking.

Comment: Hi,I am not able to download the Maven Android plugin.I have been trying since yesterday.Any idea from where I can do this??And how do I set it up for use??

Comment: Check my revised answer on how to set it up.
I just tried to install the plugin myself and was able to download the plugin successfully from the Eclipse Marketplace.
What is going wrong? Any error messages?

Answer (score 1):

Last update: it seems that the name of the artifact is android-maven-plugin now: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2/android-maven-plugin/3.6.0

So it should be like this:

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
      <artifactId>android</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.3</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <build>
       <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
               <configuration>
                   <source>1.6</source>
                   <target>1.6</target>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
               <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <configuration>
                   <sdk>
                      <path>${env.ANDROID_HOME}</path>
                       <platform>10</platform>
                   </sdk>
                   <deleteConflictingFiles>true</deleteConflictingFiles>
               </configuration>
               <extensions>true</extensions>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
    </build>
```