# Android with maven? Apk unknown

Tags: java, android, maven

Cannot get Android to work with maven. What could be the problem (generated from maven quickstart archetype):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>asd</groupId>
    <artifactId>asd</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <name>asd</name>

    <properties>
        <platform.version>4.0.3</platform.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>${platform.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <androidManifestFile>${project.basedir}/AndroidManifest.xml</androidManifestFile>
                    <assetsDirectory>${project.basedir}/assets</assetsDirectory>
                    <resourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/res</resourceDirectory>
                    <nativeLibrariesDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/native</nativeLibrariesDirectory>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>15</platform>
                    </sdk>
                    <emulator>
                        <avd>Android4</avd>
                    </emulator>
                    <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Leads to:

```
Project build error: Unknown packaging: apk
```

+

```
Project build error: Unresolveable build extension: Plugin 
com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.2.0 or one of its 
dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies for 
com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:jar:3.2.0 ()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am currently using android-maven-plugin 3.1.1 for my project and give it a try with 3.2.0, It looks like Maven has some trouble downloading one of the [required dependencies](http://maven-android-plugin-m2site.googlecode.com/svn/dependencies.html) `emma-2.1.5320.jar` from Maven Central Repository, however, I have tired `mvn clean install` several times and finally get emma-2.1.5320.jar downloaded.

Try running `mvn clean install` several times, if it still doesn't work, download and install it manually, emma-2.1.5320.jar with source and javadoc are available on [Maven Central Repository](http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C1823407290):

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=emma-2.1.5320.jar \
                     -Dsources=emma-2.1.5320-sources.jar \
                     -Djavadoc=emma-2.1.5320-javadoc.jar \
                     -DgroupId=emma \
                     -DartifactId=emma \
                     -Dversion=2.1.5320 \
                     -Dpackaging=jar
```

You should be able to use android-maven-plugin 3.2.0 now, hope this helps.

Answer (score 10):

I had same problem because I had android plugin added in `<build><pluginManagement>` section of configuration.

Moving it to `<build><plugins>` solved my issue.

Comment: This worked for me when upgrading android-maven-plugin from 3.7.0 to 3.9.0-rc.2.

Answer (score 6):

Add `extensions` option to your `android-maven-plugin` configuration.

> **extensions**
>
> Whether to load Maven extensions
>   (such as packaging and type handlers) from this plugin.

Sample configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.9.0-rc.2</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <sdk>
            <platform>${android.platform}</platform>
        </sdk>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This solves probem with **apk** unknown packaging.

Answer (score 4):

Replace the  `<version>3.2.0</version>` with  `<version>3.6.0</version>` and then clean and then install the package. 3.6.0 is the latest version of android-maven-plugin.

Answer (score 2):

You have installed the "normal" Maven plugin that works for Java projects (and .jar files). For Android you need the Maven Android Plugin

Have a look in to this

[Error in pom file in Maven project after importing into Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452754/error-in-pom-file-in-maven-project-after-importing-into-eclipse)