# Android Maven Project - getting error in pom.xml

Tags: android, maven, m2eclipse

I got this error when i adding this line to my pom.xml file in maven project

Here is my pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>GROUPID</groupId>
<artifactId>ARTIFACTID</artifactId>
<version>VERSION</version>
<packaging>apk</packaging>  <!-- Getting error in this line -->
<name>NAME</name>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
        <version>r6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <androidManifestFile>${project.basedir}/AndroidManifest.xml</androidManifestFile>
                    <assetsDirectory>${project.basedir}/assets</assetsDirectory>
                    <resourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/res</resourceDirectory>
                    <nativeLibrariesDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/native</nativeLibrariesDirectory>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>9</platform>
                    </sdk>
                    <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>project.local</id>
        <name>project</name>
        <url>file:${project.basedir}/repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

I am getting this error when adding pom.xml in apk.

I referred to this question [Android with maven? Apk unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610564/android-with-maven-apk-unknown)

But **mvn clean install** doesn't help me... 
So please help me to get rid of this error.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Try moving those plugins, particularly the android-maven-plugin outside of <pluginManagement>.  When specified inside <pluginManagement> they don't run so the android-maven-plugin extension isn't seen so maven doesn't know what to do with the "apk" packaging.

Comment: Thanks tdrury for response. I tried removing that also but again got that issue. Later i tried deleting the repository folder inside .m2 in home and run the command mvn clean install in the terminal. I repeated this for lot number times which ended up in clearing the issue.