# Unknown packaging apk

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, pom.xml, android-build

I am trying to import an existing android application in eclipse. Eclipse is complaining about unknown packaging apk.

Maven 3.2.1 version. I tried different configurations under plugin xml tag but nothing works.

Below is my pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>android</artifactId>
<version>4.7.0</version>
<packaging>apk</packaging>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.google.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[1.0.0,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>generate-sources</goal>
                                        <goal>proguard</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore/>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<name>Test app</name>
<description>Test</description>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to import? Do you have the source code or a JAR file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android with maven? Apk unknown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610564/android-with-maven-apk-unknown)

Comment: I already looked at other post answers and not working...

Comment: Does this fail on the command line as well?

Answer (score 4):

If the POM you're quoted above is complete, it looks as though you haven't added the [android-maven-plugin](https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/) to the `pluginManagement` section of your POM.

Something like this:

```
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
      <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.9.0-rc.2</version>
      <extensions>true</extensions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

Answer (score 0):

A google search for [unknown packaging apk](https://www.google.com/search?q=unknown+packaging+apk&oq=unknown+packag&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l2j69i60j0.4336j0j1&client=ubuntu-browser&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) turns up [this blog](http://lexaux.blogspot.com/2013/02/building-android-application-with-maven.html). It appears that you need the following `<dependency>`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupid>com.google.android</groupId>
    <artifactid>android</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Unknown packaging apk is related to android-maven-plugin, not API.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what exact solution is but i did below stuff and it worked:

1) Deleted maven repo and settings file and recreated new from scratch

2) I had maven plugin earlier but made changes to it as below.

`<build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>19</platform>
                    </sdk>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>`

3) mvn clean install from command line.

Comment: `<extensions>true</extensions>` is REQUIRED to recognize apk packaging.

Comment: This is impossible. Check your pluginManagment settings in pom or parent pom.