# Android with maven and Unresolveable build extension: Plugin com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.9.0-rc.3

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven

I am creating a POM file for an Android Project on Maven in Eclipse IDE. I also modified my proxy settings in the settings.xml file. I am getting two errors on the command prompt: 
1)

```
Project build error: Unresolveable build extension: Plugin 
 com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.9.0-rc.3 or one of its dependencies 
 could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: 
 com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:jar:3.9.0-rc.3, 
 com.google.guava:guava:jar:13.0.1, com.android.tools:sdklib:jar:22.4.2, org.apache.commons:commons-
 compress:jar:1.0, com.android.tools.build:builder:jar:0.7.3, org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.48, 
 net.sf.kxml:kxml2:jar:2.3.0, com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:jar:22.4.2, com.android.tools.lint:lint:jar:22.4.2, 
 org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.14, org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guice:jar:3.1.0, 
 org.sonatype.sisu.inject:guice-bean-locators:jar:2.3.0, javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar:1.0, 
 org.sonatype.sisu.inject:guice-plexus-locators:jar:2.3.0: Failure to transfer 
 com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:jar:3.9.0-rc.3 from http://
 repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the 
 update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact 
 com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:jar:3.9.0-rc.3 from/to central (http://
 repo1.maven.org/maven2): No response received after 60000
```

and 2)

```
Project build error: Unknown packaging: apk
```

For the second error, I tried out the tips on [Android with maven? Apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610564/android-with-maven-apk-unknown) unknown, but of no avail. This is my pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>verification-samples-android</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.neurotec.samples</groupId>
        <version>9.0.0.0</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>face-verification-sample-android</artifactId>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <name>FaceVerification Sample</name>
    <build>
        <finalName>face-verification-sample</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <target
                                name="copy and rename file">
                                <copy
                                    file="${product.bin.data.directory}/FacesDetectSegmentsFeaturePointsDetect.ndf"
                                    tofile="${project.asset.data.directory}/FacesDetectSegmentsFeaturePointsDetect.ndf.jet" />
                                <copy
                                    file="${product.bin.data.directory}/FacesDetectSegmentsFeaturePointsTrack.ndf"
                                    tofile="${project.asset.data.directory}/FacesDetectSegmentsFeaturePointsTrack.ndf.jet" />
                                <copy
                                    file="${product.bin.data.directory}/FacesDetectSegmentsLiveness.ndf"
                                    tofile="${project.asset.data.directory}/FacesDetectSegmentsLiveness.ndf.jet" />
                                <copy
                                    file="${product.bin.data.directory}/FacesCreateTemplateSmall.ndf"
                                    tofile="${project.asset.data.directory}/FacesCreateTemplateSmall.ndf.jet" />
                                <copy
                                    file="${product.bin.data.directory}/FacesCreateTemplateMedium.ndf"
                                    tofile="${project.asset.data.directory}/FacesCreateTemplateMedium.ndf.jet" />
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-native-libraries</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/libs</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${product.lib.android.directory}</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>**/libjnidispatch.so</include>
                                        <include>**/libNCore.so</include>
                                        <include>**/libNLicensing.so</include>
                                        <include>**/libNBiometricClient.so</include>
                                        <include>**/libNBiometrics.so</include>
                                        <include>**/libNDevices.so</include>
                                        <include>**/libNFaceVerification.so</include>
                                        <include>**/libNGui.so</include>
                                        <include>**/libNMedia.so</include>
                                        <include>**/libNMediaProc.so</include>
                                        <include>**/libopenblas.so</include>
                                    </includes>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>armeabi/**</exclude>
                                        <exclude>x86_64/**</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>standalone</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${product.bin.directory}</outputDirectory>
                    <finalName>Android</finalName>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>src/main/assembly/standalone.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.neurotec</groupId>
            <artifactId>neurotec-core-android</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.neurotec</groupId>
            <artifactId>neurotec-biometrics-android</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.neurotec</groupId>
            <artifactId>neurotec-media-android</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.neurotec</groupId>
            <artifactId>neurotec-media-processing-android</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.neurotec</groupId>
            <artifactId>neurotec-biometrics-client-android</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.neurotec</groupId>
            <artifactId>neurotec-face-verification-android</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.neurotec</groupId>
            <artifactId>neurotec-face-verification-gui-android</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.neurotec</groupId>
            <artifactId>neurotec-devices-android</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.neurotec</groupId>
            <artifactId>neurotec-devices-media-android</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.neurotec</groupId>
            <artifactId>neurotec-biometrics-gui-android</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.neurotec</groupId>
            <artifactId>neurotec-gui-android</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <product.root.directory>${basedir}/../../../..</product.root.directory>
        <project.asset.data.directory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/combined-assets/data</project.asset.data.directory>
    </properties>
</project>
```

I would really appreciate suggestions and comments. Also, I am using the following version of maven and java:

Answer (score 1):

Run Command

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

make sure eclipse can see the libs. this meant going to the projectsetup/buildpath/libraries editor in eclipse and adding the variable M2_REPO to point to your local maven repository (e.g. something like `/home/nacho3d/.m2/repository`)

Your error, actually, looks to me like maven can't find a dependency for android-maven-plugin.

If it not works, then you need to set proxy: [Configuring a proxy](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html)

### Setting.xml file location

There are two locations where a settings.xml file may live:

> The Maven install: $M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml
>
> A user's install: ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml

Comment: Then configure proxy from here http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html

Comment: Where can I find settings.xml file ?

Comment: What is the value of $M2_HOME ?

Comment: @SagorAhmed That is maven home folder. In windows it looks like `C:\apache-maven-3.3.9\conf`

Comment: How can I find username and password ?

Answer (score 0):

add this line of code in your pom.xml and try to rebuild your project.

> this PluginManagement Might help you out.

```
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
      <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.9.0-rc.2</version>
      <extensions>true</extensions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

as well as you should add this dependency into your Project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupid>com.google.android</groupId>
    <artifactid>android</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

then use the command

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse // to reset all .classpath files
```

and

```
mvn clean
```

Not sure but might resolve your problem  I hope.

Comment: After your editing my xml file looks like this : http://paste.ofcode.org/r9AQZEKg8KnjgRE7GVsvD9 . But same error exists .